# Usando la API de Age of Empires , error

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy usando la API de [Age of Empire 2](https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/units)

El caso es que quiero mostrar por un gráfico el atributo "name" y el "build_time" , pero a la hora de pillarlo me salta este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es este:

```
 var datoAux5 = [];
 var datoAux6 = [];
 var api3 = "/ui/v1/takingstats/proxy3";
    $http.get(api3).then(function(response) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            datoAux5.push(response.data[i].units.name);
            console.log(datoAux5);
            datoAux6.push(response.data[i].units.build_time);
            console.log(datoAux6);

        }

        var graphdef = {
            categories: ['uvCharts'],
            dataset: {

                'uvCharts': [
                    { name: datoAux5[0], value: datoAux6[0] },
                    { name: datoAux5[1], value: datoAux6[1] },
                    { name: datoAux5[2], value: datoAux6[2] },
                    { name: datoAux5[3], value: datoAux6[3] },
                    { name: datoAux5[4], value: datoAux6[4] }

                ],

            }


        };

        var chart = uv.chart('Donut', graphdef, {
            meta: {
                caption: 'Total population in 2010 in some countries',
                hlabel: 'Years',
                vlabel: 'Number of users',
                vsublabel: 'in thousands'
            }
        });

});
```

Por lo que creo el error es porque no pilla bien los objetos , alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El error es porque algo que no es un número se está intentando usar/parsear como un número. ¿Qué valores tienen datoAux5 y datoAux6?

Comment: datoAux5 es el "name" que es String , y el datoAux6 "build_time" que es int. En el enlace que he puesto pone el tipo de las propiedades

Comment: Es un array dentro de un array , el json de la api de AoE2 , no sé si por ahí andará el problema

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve]? (Sin añadir la clave de API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, tu código se podría optimizar ya que recorres una colección para almacenar unas variables que luego solo utilizas para crear un objeto a mano. Podrías optimizarlo simplemente rellenando el array `uvCharts` directamente en el for.

En segundo lugar deberías añadir una condición para comprobar que efectivamente tus datos numéricos son como se espera, números:

```
    let uvCharts = [];

    response.data.units.map(function(elem){
        let name = elem.name;
        let value = elem.build_time;
        if( name && value && !isNaN(value))
            uvCharts.push({"name": name, "value": value});   
    })

    var graphdef = {
        categories: ['uvCharts'],
        dataset: {
            'uvCharts': uvCharts,
        }
    };
```

Comment: Así ya no me muestra el error pero simplemente no se muestra nada , no pilla el gráfico

Comment: te lo he actualizado con un mapeo del array ya que el error podría ser que intentaras acceder a `response.data[i]` cuando creo que response.data de 1, 2 ... no existe y solo hay response.data. Con el map te ahorras conocer el numero de interaciones

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución , funciona bien. Pero me gustaría entenderlo mejor , me podría dar otro tipo de explicación? Me parece bastante interesante la solución

Comment: El método map de javascript funciona como los `foreach` de otros lenguajes y es una forma mas sencilla de recorrer colecciones de datos. Ese JSON que has puesto en el enlace es `response.data` y tiene un campo `units` que es una colección de 'n' elementos que se repiten. Con el map puedes utilizar el parametro de la funcion que le pasas al método, lo que yo he llamado `elem` para obtener los datos de cada interacción. `elem` es el primer elemento, después el segundo, luego el tercero etcetera. Simplemente recojo los valores que necesito y compruebo que el build_time es realmente un numero

Comment: Puedes encontrar más información del array.map aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

Las unidades están en `response.data.units` y debes acceder a cada unidad tal que `response.data.units[i].name`

Comment: Aún así no muestra el gráfico , con la respuesta de abajo se quitan los errores incluyendo lo de corregir el units[i] tampoco lo muestra